# how to index a string in C like a string in python?

Tags: python, c, string, substring, c-strings

For example, in python, you can index strings like this

```
some_string = "hello"
substring = some_string[0:3]
```

and substring will be "hel"

however, in C, if I have

```
char some_string[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

Is there a way to get just

```
{'h', 'e', 'l'}
```

There is probably a very simple solution that I am overlooking, but I find it hard to think in two languages sometimes.

Comment: Note that your `some_string` is *not* a C string. It lacks the null-terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very simple, primarily because of memory management. You either need `substring` to be an array of sufficiently many characters, or need to allocate the memory dynamically. for example:

```
char *some_string = "hello";
char substring[4];
strncpy(substring,some_string,3);
substring[3]='\0';
```

or:

```
char *substring(char *s, int start, int len)
{
    char *s2= malloc(len+1);
    strncpy(s2, s+start, len);
    s2[len]='\0';
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: Note: you'll need to check for `start <= strlen(s))`, too. (plus: `strncpy()` makes no sense here. (it seldom does))

Comment: @wildplasser, suggestions for alternative to `strncpy`?

Comment: Maybe just strcpy() or even memcpy() ?

Comment: @wildplasser, `strcpy()` won't do because not till end-of-string may need to be copied. `memcpy()` could do. What is wrong with `strncpy()`?

Answer (score 2):

For starters this declaration of a character array

```
char some_string[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

does not contain a string.

You should write either

```
char some_string[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

or

```
char some_string[] = {"hello"};
```

or

```
char some_string[] = "hello";
```

The only way to get a substring is to copy the sub-range of characters in another character array.

for example

```
#include <string.h>

// ...

char substring[4];

strncpy( substring, some_string, 3 );
substring[3] = '\0';
```

Comment: I would consider using `memcpy` rather than `strncpy` here.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons In general a copied string can be less than the requested range.

Comment: That is true in a general case, but I got the impression that we were dealing with a scenario in which we knew the substring to be copied was full-length.  Especially considering the OP is looking for it to be equivalent to giving a range in a python string.